# Проблема с импортом Go

Tags: golang

`.bash.rc` содержит следующую информацию:

```
...
export GOPATH="$HOME/TEST/go"
export PATH="$PATH:/home/ivan/TEST/go/bin"
```

Структура каталогов `Go`:

```
TEST
 |-go
 |  |-bin
 |  |-pkg
 |  |-src
 |     |-types
 |         |-types.go
 |-task
     |-task.go
```

в types лежит следующий код:

```
package types

type Response struct {
    Items   []map[string]string `json: "items"`
    Count   int                 `json: "count"`
}

type Request struct {
    Oper    string              `json: "oper"`
    Params  map[string]string   `json: "params"`
}
```

Делаю в `types` `go install`
В `task.go` импорт:

```
import (
    ...
    _ "types"
)
```

Далее, в `task.go` участок кода, где создается переменные

```
var res Response
var res Request
```

При запуске `go run task.go` вылетают ошибки:

```
undefined: Request
undefined: Response
```

Прочитал похожие темы и статьи на Хабре, сделал задание со строками из документации, но все равно не пойму, что я сделал не так. Где ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, с Go 1.11 про GOPATH можно [забывать](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

Во-вторых, то, что вы сделали, это пустой импорт. Если вы хотите импортировать в нынешний пакет все экспортируемые идентификаторы из другого проекта, это делается через:

```golang
import . "types"
```

Однако такая форма [не рекомендуется нигде, кроме тестов](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#import-dot). Так что пишите

```golang
import "types"

var res types.Response
var req types.Request
```

Если не хотите, чтобы в обществе приличных гоферов вас засмеяли :-)